# How to update an ActiveRecord and its "has_and_belongs_to_many" related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have simple 2 related models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :emails
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

How can an instance of a user get updated, if I change its emails array:

```
@user = User.new(username: "ben", password: "ben123")
@user.emails.build(:address: "ben@email.com", app: "outlook")
@user.save!
@user.update(password: "321neb", emails: [{id: 1, app: "gmail"}])
```

The update line won't work for me, so what's the right way to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `attributes` to indicate that you are updating the nested model

```
@user.update(password: "321neb", emails_attributes: [{id: 1, app: "gmail"}])
```